# How to distribute multiple clips on the timeline, by Date and the time of the first one?

Tags: video, premiere, video-quality, adobe

I have an existing project in Adobe Premiere 2017 and I would like to import multiple clips in it.

I already have the primary camera in sync with the Audio, and I would like to bring the secondary camera consisting of multiple clips which are not continous (there are time gaps between them).

By knowing that the video `123.MOV` created at `1:39 PM` should be at minute `7:55` on my timeline, and after making sure it is in sync with the audio, I want the other ones to be set in sync as well, adding the timestamps between the `Created Date` on the timeline.

I am not sure if Timecode helps here, but I am wondering if there is a way to **import them in the project with the time gaps between them** and then I will be able to select them all and sync them at once.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Davinci Resolve, I would solve this problem by creating a multicam clip using Timecode as the method for synchronization and keeping clips organized by camera.  This will create a multicam clip with only a single camera, but each clip spaced out according to its timecode.  If you like, the multicam clip can then be decomposed in place and converted into a compound clip, preserving the spacing between the video clips.  You can then place the single compound clip to start at 7:55 and all the rest of the clips inside the compound clip (or multicam clip if you didn't convert to compound clip) should line up as expected.

Comment: I tried using the Timecode multicam sequence, but I didn't have much success with it and ended by placing them manually. It could be the created at is not interpreted correctly...

Comment: When I do event recording, there's an audio track that runs through the entire event.  That long-running track provides a timecode reference against which the video clips can be placed.  Resolve is also not exactly happy to merely place clips in space against an abstract timeline that starts at 00:00:00:00 and runs through 23:59:59:23 (or whatever).